# javascript function to test conditions under specific browser size

Tags: javascript, testing, viewport

Trying to write a function that will test conditions with certain browser window size using JavaScript.
For example:

```
if ( window.width <= 500 && window.height <= 500){
do something ;
}else{
do something;
```

Are there any existing commands for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.  Those should give you the viewport width and height respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if you are running in a browser, you can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, or also `window.clientWidth` and `window.clientHeight`.

There are little differences, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

Answer (score 0):

Use window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth and set them in variables to work with for example..

```
const height = window.screen.availHeight
const width window.screen.availWidth

if(width) {
do something}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I set height and weight values to these commands? Or it's just returns value? What I'm trying to do is to write a script/condition to click on an element on a page. Element is visible when browser page in a small viewport. Like if width and height is "value", then click on element.